# Sidebar does not want to change background color when specified in CSS3

Tags: html, css

I am coding a css3 and htm5 website and I ran into a problem where even when I change all of the classes for my sidebar "top-sidebar" it does not want to change background color. The fore color changes but the background does not want to change. Because it is a mess of 500 lines i will just put the lines that are about the top-sidebar.
HTML5:

```
        <aside class="top-sidebar">
            <article>
            <h2>Top Sidebar</h2>
            <p>Discover how to use new techniques to achieve an outstanding, cross-browser HTML5.</p>
            </article>
        </aside>
```

CSS3

```
    .top-sidebar {
        background-color:#82a213;
        width: 86%;
        float: left;
        border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
        background-color: #FFF; 
        margin-top: 4%;
        margin-left: 0;
        padding: 0 7%;
        margin-bottom: 0;       
    }

    .top-sidebar p {
        background-color:#82a213;
        width: 90%;
    }
.top-sidebar {
    background-color:#82a213;
    color:black;
    width: 24%;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 2%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
    background-color: #FFF; 
    padding: 2% 3%;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
}
```

The result is(Look at the top side bar on the right top side):
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overriding the background color in the same class ^^

```
background-color:#82a213;
background-color: #FFF;
```

CSS is Cascade Style Sheets, what means that the lowest rule will override the above